# How to Modify Momentum of SGD optimizer in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, keras

I now that there is a fixed momentum update in SGD. I am trying to add custom adaptive momentum to SGD optimizer. According to source code;

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizers.py

The momentum is described under `def_updates` function.

I want my momentum updated in every iteration. Should i add modified momentum calculation ( `self.momentum = #do smt`) into `def get_updates`?

Comment: Have you solved the problem ? I'm trying to do it in Tensorflow 2. If so, can describe it in detail here ?

Comment: Hello , yes . According to the tensorflow documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback) , i have created a callback function  (on_epoch_end) and passed it to the model.fit  callbacks